# MySQL Inserting Multiple Columns and Rows into a Temporary Table

Tags: mysql

I have a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp`
AS (
 SELECT COUNT(*) as count, YEAR(end_date)
 FROM a
 WHERE column_1 = "some_condition"
 GROUP BY YEAR(end_date)
);
```

I then try to add on new values into this table

```
INSERT INTO temp (count, year)
VALUES(
  SELECT COUNT(*) as count, year(end_date)
  FROM b
  WHERE column_1 = "some_condition"
  GROUP BY YEAR(end_date)
);
```

And this line throws error.
Error given:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count, year(end_date)   FROM b
> WHERE column_1 = "some condition" ' at line 3

What I'm trying to achieve is for the new rows and columns which were selected to be inserted into the temporary table. Any ideas?

After the first query, temp table should look like this:

```
count  year
3      2012
20     2013
104    2011
```

And the selected results from the second query looks like this

```
count  year
6      2013
```

The expected outcome:

```
count  year
3      2012
20     2013
104    2011
6      2013
```

Comment: "And this line throws error." You should probably edit your question and add that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the "VALUES" in your Insert statement
Syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

```
INSERT INTO `temp` (`count`, `year`)
  SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    year(`end_date`)
  FROM `b`
  WHERE `column_`` = "condition" GROUP BY YEAR(end_date);
```